# Can't get the EditText to be read only once a action has occured

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-xml

So I have been trying to get This TextInputEditText to be read only once a description called "Service Call" is selected. Here's the code:

```
processViewModel.isServiceCall.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){isServiceCall ->
    if (isServiceCall){
        val surveyDateAndTime: String = DateUtil.localFullDateToDateStringFormatted(
            Date()
        )
        processViewModel.surveySiteFormInfo
            .siteSurveyStepOneInfo
            .surveyDataAndTimeWorkPerformedInfo
            .surveyDateAndTime = surveyDateAndTime


            room_add_layout?.isEnabled = false
            room_add_layout?.setOnClickListener(null)
    }
    else{
        processViewModel.surveySiteFormInfo
            .siteSurveyStepOneInfo
            .surveyDataAndTimeWorkPerformedInfo
            .surveyDateAndTime = ""

    }

} //isServiceCall being "Service Call"
```

I just need the view to be a read only view and grey text once the isServiceCall is "Service Call". I appreciate it, thank you.

Comment: Can you debug the app by adding a breakpoint at line `room_add_layout?.isEnabled = false` to see if this line is actually getting executed?

Comment: I did the debug and add a breakpoint to that line of code. It did reach it.

Comment: Ok, it reaches that point but, did that line actually execute? I mean, did you check if `room_add_layout` is `null`? Because, if `room_add_layout` is null, `.isEnabled = false` will not be executed!